# How can I bring multiple class objects into one class using DataContext?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am making a Winodws Phone 7 program, I've got another question. So, my question concerns, how would I bring in two classes using one datacontext? My code currently looks like:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = App.ViewModel;
    }
```

Now, what I want to do is add another Model:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = App.ViewModel, App.ViewModel2;
    }
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

How would I make it to where I can have two objects in one form?

This is a silverlight / Windows Phone 7 application.

I need to have 2 modules loaded as one is for Accounts and the other is for Buddies, and I don't want 10 different pages as it'd look nicer with just one page for all the normal things.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need an object that contains both.

```
DataContext = new { VM1 = App.ViewModel, VM2 = App.ViewModel2 }
```

I would not use an anonymous type, just an example, since you want support for INotifyPropertyChanged. Basically you are looking for [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

Comment: Thanks - That did work, however, I think I found a different more secure way to do it, because all the items are in a listbox I set the listbox's datacontext to the object.